# Does XML Serialization Require Properties to be Read/Write?

Tags: c#, properties, xml-serialization

I'm testing XML Serialization in my class, but i noticed that the ID number didn't get saved when i ran the program.

So i was looking around and modifying a few things but nothing worked, then i saw that all fields except ID had both get and set properties. So i added a set; property to my ID number and poof it worked.
The question is, does it have to be set; and get; function on all my properties for XML Serialization to work?

I don't want the ID number to be modified after the object has been created (its automatically generated).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is basically a restriction of XML serialization. From the [XML Serialization docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(VS.85).aspx):

> Only public properties and fields can
>   be serialized. Properties must have
>   public accessors (get and set
>   methods). If you must serialize
>   non-public data, use the
>   BinaryFormatter class rather than XML
>   serialization.

XML serialization isn't as flexible as one might like.

Comment: I noticed he didn't mention which version of the framework he was using. Wasn't this changed in .NET 3.5?

Comment: While it may be a verbatim quote from MSDN, I wouldn't necessarily advocate BinarySerializer as an alternative for those scenarios where xml was the previous option...

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to serialize non-public data as xml, `DataContractSerializer` might be useful. It isn't as flexible as `XmlSerializer` (and you can't specify attributes), but it can serialize non-public data:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    private int id;

    public int Id {get {return id;}} // immutable

    public Person(int id) { this.id = id; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get;set;} // mutable
}
```

Note also that it doesn't use your constructor... or indeed *any* constructor - it cheats, allowing it to create an object and fill the data in afterwards.