# XslCompiledTransform with objects and XSLT

Tags: asp.net, object, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have added some properties and local variables to a class and would like to parse the object with XSLT to an XML/HTMLfile.

Now here is the strange thing: 
when I have this:

```
private double _invoicePrice = 0;

[XmlAttribute("invoicePrice")]
public double InvoicePrice{
    get { return _invoicePrice; }
    set { _invoicePrice = value; }
}

[XmlAttribute("vat")]
public double Vat
{
    get
    {
        return 4;

        /* // also tried this...
        double shopVat = 19;
        double vat = (_invoicePrice / (shopVat + 100)) * shopVat;
        return Math.Round(vat, 2);
        */
    }
}
```

the parsing does **not** work

and when I have this:

```
private double _invoicePrice = 0;
private double _vat = 0;

[XmlAttribute("invoicePrice")]
public double InvoicePrice{
    get { return _invoicePrice; }
    set { _invoicePrice = value; }
}

[XmlAttribute("vat")]
public double Vat
{
    get { return _vat; }
    set { _vat = value; }
}
```

the transformation **works**!

The property `Vat` always had a value while debugging! with both options. But somehow the `XslCompiledTransform` requires private variables or no read-only or something?

Can someone explain why option 2 works and the first does not..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you need a setter.

**EDIT 2: Reason for setter**

[Does XML Serialization Require Properties to be Read/Write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154793/does-xml-serialization-require-properties-to-be-read-write)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28VS.85%29.aspx

**END EDIT 2**

For now if you try:

```
private double _invoicePrice = 0;

[XmlAttribute("invoicePrice")]
public double InvoicePrice{
    get { return _invoicePrice; }
    set { _invoicePrice = value; }
}

[XmlAttribute("vat")]
public double Vat
{
    get
    {
        double shopVat = 19;
        double vat = (_invoicePrice / (shopVat + 100)) * shopVat;
        return Math.Round(vat, 2);
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

The setter is the only bit I have changed really.

You dont need to set the value to anything, but it does then allow the get to run and return your Vat value.

**EDIT**
a suggestion might be to allow the set to pass in that `shopVAT` for use in the `GET`. As we all know this can change

```
private double _invoicePrice = 0;
private double _shopVat = 0;

[XmlAttribute("invoicePrice")]
public double InvoicePrice{
    get { return _invoicePrice; }
    set { _invoicePrice = value; }
}

[XmlAttribute("vat")]
public double Vat
{
    get
    {
        //double shopVat = 19;
        double vat = (_invoicePrice / (_shopVat + 100)) * _shopVat;
        return Math.Round(vat, 2);
    }
    set
    {
        _shopVat = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: and why do you need a setter?

Comment: If you use the set to pass in the vat value, it shouldnt really matter ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154793/does-xml-serialization-require-properties-to-be-read-write